# Hide custom taxonomy from easy admin

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm running a website that uses EasyAdmin (for user content generation).

I created two taxonomies (via functions.php) for my own needs, but now my users can see them when they are adding their content to the website.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_item_nominations' );

function create_item_nominations() {
  register_taxonomy(
      'nominations',
      'ait-dir-item',
      array(
          'label' => __( 'Nominations' ),
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'nominations' ),
          'hierarchical' => true,
      )
  );
}
```

I can hide them with CSS but that's not a really nice solution, more like a workaround for a while.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like just setting `show_ui` to `false` will do what you're after - it will hide the taxonomy in the admin menu, and it won't create a metabox on the post edit page.

After this:

`'hierarchical' => true,`

Add this:

`'show_ui' => false,`

You'll find a full reference of all the available arguments over at the Wordpress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

**EDIT:** (thanks to Howdy_McGee in the comments)

This will hide from all backend users including admins. If you want the taxonomy to be visible just for admins but not lower level users, instead use:

`'show_ui' => current_user_can( 'administrator' ),`

Instead of 'administrator' here, you can also use any role at https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities if you want more fine-grained control.

Comment: I only need to hide it from users, but setting show_ui to false hides it from admin too

Comment: @Bazinga This is correct, instead of assigning `true` or `false`, instead you can assign [`current_user_can( 'administrator' )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) which returns boolean if an admin is viewing the post type.

Comment: I've edited the post and added your fix @Howdy_McGee!

Comment: How did you go with this @Bazinga?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that via EasyAdmin (unless you change the code in the plugin).  'show_ui' is for the actual wordpress admin, it might work there but it would also remove it from the actual wordpress admin that you use.

Comment: yes, false 'show_ui" hide it from admin too, but I need it.